# Alternate screensaver settings on different X instances

Tags: xorg, x11, vnc, screensaver

On my desktop system, I run two instances of X-- one is associated with the physical screen, one is associated with a virtual screen (a la `vncserver`).
I use the physical one to do things related to being physically present (e.g., mess with local equipment) and I use the virtual one for doing things that transcend and persist across my visits.  I connect locally/remotely to the virtual/vncserver instance and all works great... until my default screensaver kicks in.  The screensaver runs fine and independently on both instances.  But when I'm connected remotely to the virtual instance and become inactive, the screensaver burns up bandwidth.

I could change my default screensaver to be something less visually active, but for a variety of reasons, I like having it active on the physical instance.

Given that screensaver's behavior is controlled via a file-based configuration, it seems like there should be a way to have different screensaver settings for different displays (especially since [you can have different Xorg configurations](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19340/how-can-i-run-a-separate-x-session-on-a-different-physical-display)).  Nothing is leaping out at me though-- is it not as easy as it seems like it should be?

Note: If it matters, this is on a Centos 6.x system with Gnome 2.something